# Multiply method for a binary list

Tags: python, algorithm, binary

I am passing parameters x and y to this multIter class in the console as follows:

```
import BigInteger as bi 

x =bi.BigInteger([1,0,1,1])
y= bi.BigInteger([1,0,0,1])
bi.BigInteger.multIter(x,y)
```

I am currently getting the wrong answers when I call this method. There is some logical error in the line  answer = self.add(x), that I am not able to figure out.

```
def multIter(self,y):  
    a_bits = self._bits
    b_bits = y._bits
    
    answer = 0
    
    for i in range(0,len(b_bits)):
        if(b_bits[i] == 1):
            x= self.multByPow2(i)
            answer = self.add(x)
           
    return answer
```

Comment: Which answer do you get, and which answer did you hope to get instead, and why?

Comment: What is `BigInteger`? Wild guess: you want the result of `x.multIter(y)`.

Comment: What number does [1, 0, 1, 1] represent? Eleven or thirteen? In other words, are the bits listed in least-to-most significant order, or vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is indeed a logical error at the statement you indicate. In each iteration that has a 1-bit, that `answer = self.add(x)` assignment ignores the previous value of `answer`, and just overwrites it. You should not add `x` to `self`, but add `x` to `answer`. For that to work, `answer` must be initialised as an instance of `BigInteger`, and not as 0.

So replace that part of the code with:

```
        answer = bi.BigInteger([0])
        
        for i in range(0,len(b_bits)):
            if b_bits[i] == 1:
                x = self.multByPow2(i)
                answer = answer.add(x)
```

This will work fine assuming the other used methods of `BigInteger` have been correctly implemented.